# List recent posts of a specific user in a Views block

Tags: views, users

I'm trying to output a list that shows the 12 latest 'Articles' of a specific user. This list needs to be in a sidebar that is located on the frontpage.

In this sidebar visitors can click a thumbnail at the top to view some info about the author (a registered Drupal user). There's the full name, with a short bio and a picture. But there also needs to be that list that shows the user's latest articles.

So far I'm not be able to get this list to work because I can't make the list for that specific user exclusively. I found some tutorials that kind of tries to achieve the same ([like this one](https://groups.drupal.org/node/129979#comment-751473)) using the contextual filter in Views. But so far, none of them works.

I've included a screenshot of the sidebar so you have an idea how I set it up. The block in the sidebar is a View and are all User fields.

[image: Sidebar user info]

Comment: How do you select the "specific user" in the front page?

Comment: I used a Views block to make these rounded pictures at the top selectable. The block has the User: Uid and User: Picture fields with the Uid field excluded. I used an attachment in the same View with all the other information like: Full name, bio and the picture (this is the bottom region of this block). The excluded Uid was used for the attachment row class. So I can hide these divs and 'show' them with jQuery if you click the specific/individual user at the top.

Comment: Looks like you found the answer yourself. I suggest you "move" that comment to a real answer (I "like" it) ...